# How do I make an object within json_build_object()?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres query that starts like this.

```
SELECT json_build_object( 
    'type', 'Feature', 
    'properties', pop_density, 
)
```

That returns something like `{"type":"Feature", "properties":10000}`. I want it to return `{"type":"Feature", "properties": {pop_density: 10000}}`.

How do I change my query to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `json_build_object` to make 'properties' object

```
select json_build_object('type', 'type_val', 'properties', 
                                             json_build_object('pop_density', 'pop_val'));
```